# How do I set a comboBox.selecteditem

Tags: c#

I have:

```
ComboBox.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ImageLayout));
```

but how do I set the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to an `ImageLayout` value?

I tried..

```
LayOutCB.SelectedItem = (int)ImageLayout.Center;
```

but I get an exception

---

#### Update:

originally I was trying to set the `SelectedItem` in the constructor of the `UserControl`.

I added the event Handler

```
this.Load += new EventHandler(PageSettings_Load);
```

and then set the combobox.SelectedItem in there.

```
void PageSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                 
  LayOutCB.SelectedItem = ImageLayout.Center;
}
```

Works real good now.

so what was that about? can someone explain please.

Comment: Were you setting it before or after InitializeComponent()?

Comment: yes it was being set after the InitializeComponent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you not tried this?

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = ImageLayout.Center
```

It works perfectly fine for me.

---

#### Edit:

With regards to your update, I believe you are setting the `SelectedItem` before calling `InitializeComponent()` and the combo box was not created yet give you the object reference exception (the box was defined but not assigned.)

Comment: it throws an exception of "Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object"

Comment: Then you have to post more code, because on a simple form with a combobox, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = (int)ImageLayout.Foo;
```

replacing `int` with the underlying type of your enumeration.  Honestly it may just work without the cast but I am not anywhere near `csc.exe` right now.

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox` control in Windows.Forms is a *wrapper* around the underlying Windows Control. This is a common pattern - most of the Windows.Forms controls are this kind of wrapper.

Some of the properties of the ControlBox - like SelectedItem - cannot be set until *after* the underlying Windows **handle** is created. Typically, handle creation occurs when the control is first displayed.

When in your User Control's constructor, this code:

```
LayOutCB.SelectedItem = (int)ImageLayout.Center;
```

would have thrown an exception because the handle was unavailable. It worked later on (in your event handler) because the handle was available.